# Instalar Proyecto de Laravel IIS 8 Windows Server 2012

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, iis

Estoy implementando un proyecto laravel en IIS 8 Windows Server 2012. Pero tengo problemas para que las rutas funcionen. Puedo ver el index pero cuando quiero acceder a una vista me devuelve error 404. Alguien ha tenido experiencia haciendo esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya esta solventado. Para quienes quieran hacerlo y no morir en el intento asegurarse de que este bien configurado el componente "Reescritura de direcciones URL" en IIS. El resto IIS lo hace automáticamente.